# Changing in-code Dag ID won't change dag id once added to list with Python

Tags: airflow

The question might seems quite candid but I'm fairly new to Airflow. I was actually trying to explore a bit further than the tutorial and change the schedule to 'schedule=timedelta(minutes=30)'.

I tried to "re-add" it by using python dags/tutorial.py.

Now I've seen that you need to change the tag id to actually have a change to the schedule, but here where my problem starts :

even by changing the tag id, the description, and the python filename all together : adding the dag with the command 'python new_dag_name.py' adds tutorial dag id to the list, even though I deleted it. (I tried both from the GUI and command line. Also using airflow db clean).

It is really frustrating especially because I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

This is the new dag config ! with new filename.
`with DAG( "completelynewp", # These args will get passed on to each operator # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization default_args={ "depends_on_past": False, "email": ["airflow@example.com"], "email_on_failure": False, "email_on_retry": False, "retries": 1, "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5), # 'queue': 'bash_queue', # 'pool': 'backfill', # 'priority_weight': 10, # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1), # 'wait_for_downstream': False, # 'sla': timedelta(hours=2), # 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300), # 'on_failure_callback': some_function, # or list of functions # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function, # or list of functions # 'on_retry_callback': another_function, # or list of functions # 'sla_miss_callback': yet_another_function, # or list of functions # 'trigger_rule': 'all_success' }, description="Not the same description ?????????", schedule=timedelta(minutes=30), start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1), catchup=False, tags=["example"], ) as dag:`

And the result is still the same : it adds "tutorial" to dag list, with no change to it.

What am I doing wrong please ?

I tried to change tutorial.py dag configuration to change schedule to 30minutes and changing dag ID.

The expected result is : to get a completely new dag in the dag list, that executes the same tasks as 'tutorial', but every 30 minutes.

EDIT :

Now that you mention it that it might be looking in the wrong folder, I'm confused indeed by how airflow software should be used with airflow python library. I first tried to install airflow with docker compose, which works fine to run, but then I wanted to follow the Fundamentals tutorial.

I first tried to install airflow with Docker (using compose to run all the components), and set up the home airflow folder in Users/my.name/airflow

I wasn't sure how to follow the tutorial with the commands such as airflow backfill / test / etc
nor how to add dag with python. I then installed airflow with pip in virtual env. I see now that
"whereis airflow" shows me that the path is indeed in .virtualenv folder :

/.virtualenvs/AirflowOpenMeteo/bin/airflow

The configuration returns that all the paths for airflow are in

The dag that I'm trying to add is NOT in Users/my.name/airflow/dags

but in a different folder where I'm used to store my "coding" projets :
Users/my.name/Documents/Coding/Python/AirflowOpenMeteo (The idea is that I'm trying to run an ETL with Open Meteo API to learn the airflow process)

So now I'm confused.

Because how
`python Users/my.name/Documents/Coding/Python/AirflowOpenMeteo/NotTutorial.py`
Adds the same Tutorial.py that was added previously with :
`python Users/my.name/Documents/Coding/Python/AirflowOpenMeteo/Tutorial.py` when both python scripts configure the dags to have different dag id ?

Comment: You are probably not storing your dag in the directory where Airflow is looking. Which airflow tutorial are you following? Is it standalone installation?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I gave more explanation in the post edit. I hope it makes it more clear.  I'm getting confused now.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your dag to `Users/my.name/airflow/dags` because that seems to be Airflow dag folder for your virtualenv installation. There might already be a `tutorial.py` dag that came with the installation.